# Перенос текста без textwarp и сторонних библиотек в python 3

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Как можно максимально просто разбить длинную строку на ограниченные по длинне строки (скажем 50 символов), при этом не импортируя всякие textwarp и re? В конце концов тот же textwarp написан на python, просто хочу попробовать разобраться. Догадываюсь что пригодится str.split() и цикл, но пока не могу придумать как организовать.

Comment: В конце концов тот же textwarp написан на python, можно просто заглянуть в его код.

Comment: Знаете, если бы была возможность понять, я бы давно разобрался и без Вас, не регистрировался бы тут и не задавал вопросов.

Comment: попробуйте [жадный алгоритм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Algorithm), который количество строк минимизирует при разбиении (как в Ворде). Можно минимизировать количество пробелов в конце строк (~насколько грубо/неровно правый край выглядит) -- есть алгоритм, основанный динамическом программировании  ([Knuth & Plass](http://defoe.sourceforge.net/folio/knuth-plass.html)) Если поддержку Unicode добавить, то ещё интересней станет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбить на подстроки не более заданной длины элементарно:

```
lorem = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...'

def split_str(string, length):
    for i in range(0, len(string), length):
        yield string[i:i+length].strip()


print('\n'.join(split_str(lorem, 80)))
```

Разбить без разрыва слов чуть сложнее:

```
def split_by_spaces(string, length):
    lower_bound = 0
    upper_bound = 0
    last_space_position = string.rindex(' ')
    try:
        while upper_bound < len(string):
            upper_bound = string.rindex(' ', lower_bound, lower_bound + length)
            if upper_bound == last_space_position:
                upper_bound = len(string)
            if upper_bound - lower_bound > length:
                raise ValueError()
            yield string[lower_bound:upper_bound].strip()
            lower_bound = upper_bound
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Невозможно получить подстроку в заданных границах')
```

Comment: Небольшая проблема (решаемая), если в строке есть другие пробельные символы (табуляции и прочее)

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(s, n):
    l = s.split()
    for i in range(1, len(l)+1):
        if sum(map(len, l[:i])) + i - 1 > n:
            return ' '.join(l[:i-1]), ' '.join(l[i-1:])
    return s, ''

print (foo('abc def ghij abc defghj', 8)) # ('abc def', 'ghij abc defghj')
print (foo('ghij abc defghj', 8)) # ('ghij abc', 'defghj')
print (foo('asdfghjkl aa', 8)) # ('', 'asdfghjkl aa')
print (foo('as aa', 8)) # ('as aa', '')
```

`foo` возвращает 2 строки - первая часть максимальной длины не больше `n` и остаток строки, разделители - пробелы. Повторять с остатком, пока он не пуст. Если пуста первая возвращаемая строка - разбиение невозможно.

Comment: Красивый алгоритм!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev только съедает идущие подряд пробелы и медленнее вашего на порядок.

Comment: @Hivemaster не думаю, что для автора вопроса производительность так уж важна :)

Comment: Блин, оба ответа хорошие, но ответом пометить можно один(